# Is it possible to enable ACID properties on Spark 1.6.0 with Hive 2.1.1?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.6.0 with Hive 2.1.1. I have enabled ACID properties in Hive and I am able to insert/delete rows in Hive console. Now I am trying the same with Spark-sql but its not working:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
Unsupported language features in query: delete from acid_table where id=2**
```

Comment: There is not much we can do if the feature isn't supported by spark-sql. Read this https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#compatibility-with-apache-hive

Comment: SparkSQL supports a subset of features in comparison to Hive. Also, Hive ACID is enabled when you use Hive on Tez (as processing engine) along with ORC format. If you use SparkSQL, you are practically using Spark as execution engine and you may be interacting with Hive via HiveContext which is entirely different operation.